# How do I iterate a list and then return a new column using sqlContext in databricks

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to iterate through a list and create a df using a SQL query. Since sqlContext.sql returns a SQL db I figured using union would be a decent idea to combine them all into one db but I am running into a problem that I described below. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this better or how to fix it I would really appreciate it.
This is the loop I am using to iterate the list:

```
for idx, f in enumerate(row_list):
  if idx ==0:
     test = (sqlContext.sql(f" SELECT concat(domain,'_',quality,'.',sink),tablename FROM config.uploader LIKE LOWER ('%{f}%'))")
  else:
     test = (sqlContext.sql(f" SELECT concat(domain,'_',quality,'.',sink),tablename FROM config.uploader LIKE LOWER ('%{f}%'))")
  df = df.unionAll(test)
```

The expected output would be as such if say tables are named blah,blah1,blah2,blah3 etc...

```
datalake_table    | tablename 
------------------+----------
leads_silver.blah | blah
leads_bronze.blah1| blah1
leads_gold.blah2  | blah2
etc...
```

Instead, the output I get is like this

```
datalake_table     | tablename 
-------------------+----------
leads_bronze.blah4 | blah4
leads_bronze.blah4 | blah4
leads_bronze.blah4 | blah4
leads_bronze.blah4 | blah4
leads_bronze.blah4 | blah4
leads_bronze.blah4 | blah4
```

Basically, the last item in the list is writing over everything else I can't figure out what I did wrong could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your , implementation seems correct , however can also collect each `test` result inside a `list`. Then finally `union` them to get your desired results.

```
from functools import reduce

res = []

for idx, f in enumerate(row_list):
  if idx ==0:
     test = (sqlContext.sql(f" SELECT concat(domain,'_',quality,'.',sink),tablename FROM config.uploader LIKE LOWER ('%{f}%'))")
  else:
     test = (sqlContext.sql(f" SELECT concat(domain,'_',quality,'.',sink),tablename FROM config.uploader LIKE LOWER ('%{f}%'))")

  res += [ test ]

df = reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y),res)
```

Comment: Really good idea, but I get NameError: 'test' is not defined error

Comment: updated the answer , the test addition to `res` should be within the for loop

Comment: Yep I did that last night this works perfectly thank you!.